# Build a common library before building the project

Tags: java, maven

I have a library `Lib1-pom.xml` which is shared between two independent projects, `Project1-pom.xml` and `Project2-pom.xml`
Now currently I can use the library as dependency for both projects but they requires the library to be build before. I want to auto-build the library before, when I trigger the building of the project.
I have used the multi-module approach but it can't fulfill the need as this requires the library to be physically present in the module itself and available for build. Since the library is synced with git, it cannot be linked from two places.
E.g.:

```
Module 1  
ProjectModule_1-pom.xml  
 -- Project1-pom.xml  
 -- Lib1-pom.xml(synced with git)  
 -- Other libs  

Module 2  
ProjectModule_2-pom.xml    
 -- Project2-pom.xml  
 -- Lib1-pom.xml(can't be here)  
 -- Other libs


Expectation:  
Lib1-pom.xml(synced with git)  

ProjectModule_1-pom.xml      
 -- Project1-pom.xml  

Module 2  
ProjectModule_2-pom.xml      
 -- Project2-pom.xml
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: As maven is built to do stuff within a hierarchical project structure, I think it is not possible with maven alone. If you have any other CI system involved, it might be doable by some dependency mechanisms of that system.

Comment: If you’re developing all 3 projects maybe just a simple shell script will do. If you’re running from an IDE like IntelliJ you can setup “before” actions in your run configurations.

Comment: @cyberbrain I have jenkins setup for the project for daily test but I'm looking for solution on my pc while I run the project locally. There are quite many libraries so building them manually is a pain.

Comment: @Strelok whether this before action should be set for every project and one time effort? Also can it figure out the hierarchy or i have to mention the build order?

Comment: You know that you can build an extra pom-file with all your dependent projects to build them first and then build the depending projects in a second step, and you don't have to point each modules parent to the pom with the modules. But if you don't refer to your sibling modules in a proper way, maven can't figure out the build order correctly and not put them into the reactor, so you still will have to do a `mvn install` for your libs.

Comment: This is where a build server publishing to a maven repository comes in play.